# Array fields are not showing in FORM tab of ServiceStack API Explorer (/ui)

Tags: servicestack

I have this request DTO with several fields, including a string array (Sort)

```
public partial class SelectTiers : IReturn<SelectTiersResponse>, IGet
{
    public string? SearchText { get; set; }

    public string[]? Sort { get; set; }

    public int? Skip { get; set; }

    public int? Take { get; set; }
}
```

The corresponding page of the API explorer shows 3 inputs : SearchText, Skip and Take, but none for Sort.

[image]

I know it's not recommended to put complex types in GET requests but ServiceStack handles this nicely with JSV serialization.

Is there a way to show a input for these fields (at least for simples array types) ? I've tried to add a [Input(Type = "text")] to the property with no success

Edit: using ServiceStack 6.11

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only types for which there exists HTML Form Inputs will be rendered which is why no Form Inputs are rendered for any Complex Types by default.

The only built-in [Vue Component](https://docs.servicestack.net/vue/) that supports a List of strings is the [TagInput](https://docs.servicestack.net/vue/taginput) or [Combobox](https://docs.servicestack.net/vue/combobox) components which you can specify with the `[Input(Type)]` attribute, e.g:

```cs
public partial class SelectTiers : IReturn<SelectTiersResponse>, IGet
{
    public string? SearchText { get; set; }

    [Input(Type="tag")]
    public string[]? Sort { get; set; }

    public int? Skip { get; set; }

    public int? Take { get; set; }
}
```

The Combobox is a good for when you need to select from [pre-defined options](https://docs.servicestack.net/vue/combobox#auto-forms).

Alternatively you can register and use your own [Custom Vue Component](https://docs.servicestack.net/vue/custom-inputs) to manage your complex data types.

Answer (score 1):

To customize the API Explorer to display input fields for the Sort property, you can use the `ApiMember` attribute along with `DataMember` in your DTO. The `ApiMember` attribute allows you to provide additional information about how the API Explorer should display and interact with the property.

Here's an example of how you can modify your `SelectTiers` DTO:

```cs
[DataContract]
public partial class SelectTiers : IReturn<SelectTiersResponse>, IGet
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    [ApiMember(Description = "Text to search", ParameterType = "query", DataType = "string", IsRequired = false)]
    public string? SearchText { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    [ApiMember(Description = "Array of sorting criteria", ParameterType = "query", DataType = "string", IsRequired = false)]
    public string[]? Sort { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    [ApiMember(Description = "Number of items to skip", ParameterType = "query", DataType = "int", IsRequired = false)]
    public int? Skip { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    [ApiMember(Description = "Number of items to take", ParameterType = "query", DataType = "int", IsRequired = false)]
    public int? Take { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's not working still no input, but the description is showing in the "details" section

Comment: Use a Nested DTO: Instead of having a string array directly in SelectTiers, you can create a nested DTO specifically for sorting